# jQuery form submit not working php

Tags: php, jquery, html

I am creating a form that need to be submit using jQuery. Below is my code -

```
<script src="js/app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<form method="post" class="needs-validation" id="new-item" action="admin-add-inventory2.php">
<div class="mb-3">
                                    <label>Item Name</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="itemname" name="itemname" placeholder="Item name" required>                     
                                    <span id='inmessage'>
                                </div>

                                <div class="mb-3">
                                    <label>Description
                                        <span class="text-muted">(Optional)</span>
                                    </label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="description" name="description" placeholder="description...">
                                    <span id='dmessage'>
                                </div>
<hr class="mb-4">
                                <input type="submit" value="Add To Inventory" name="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block error-w3l-btn">
                            </form>
                            <div id="form-messages"></div>
```

Code for app.js --

```
$(function() {

    // Get the form.
    var form = $('#new-item');

    // Get the messages div.
    var formMessages = $('#form-messages');

    // Set up an event listener for the contact form.
    $(form).submit(function(e) {
        // Stop the browser from submitting the form.
        e.preventDefault();

        // Serialize the form data.
        var formData = $(form).serialize();

        // Submit the form using AJAX.
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: $(form).attr('action'),
            data: formData
        })
        .done(function(response) {
            // Make sure that the formMessages div has the 'success' class.
            $(formMessages).removeClass('error');
            $(formMessages).addClass('success');

            // Set the message text.
            $(formMessages).text(response);

            // Clear the form.
            $('#itemname').val('');
            $('#description').val('');
        })
        .fail(function(data) {
            // Make sure that the formMessages div has the 'error' class.
            $(formMessages).removeClass('success');
            $(formMessages).addClass('error');

            // Set the message text.
            if (data.responseText !== '') {
                $(formMessages).text(data.responseText);
            } else {
                $(formMessages).text('Oops! An error occured, please try again.');
            }
        });

    });

});
```

But when pressing the **submit button**, **app.js** is not getting executed. Its directly going to **action="admin-add-inventory2.php" of form tag**.

Kindly point me the logic i m missing.

**Its not taking the question in stackoverflow due to more code and less text, so i am adding extra text to submit. Pls ignore the below text.**

But when pressing the **submit button**, **app.js** is not getting executed. Its directly going to **action="admin-add-inventory2.php" of form tag**.

Kindly point me the logic i m missing.

But when pressing the **submit button**, **app.js** is not getting executed. Its directly going to **action="admin-add-inventory2.php" of form tag**.

Kindly point me the logic i m missing.

Comment: Are you loading jquery script? do you have console errors? try to wrap your js code into `$(document).ready(function(){});` or move your script after body tag

Comment: Do you get any error in firebug while submit ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please replace button type from submit to button.

Eg: `<input type="button" value="Add To Inventory" name="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block error-w3l-btn">`

Also replace `$(form).submit(function(e) {` with `$("#submit").click(function(e) {` if you want to call the AJAX code in your JS file on click of the button.

Comment: You should add an explanation as to how this will help.